# VBA Excel: Filter a column

Tags: vba, excel, filter

I am trying to filter a column as I had many times earlier. But getting error as below:

> 1004: "Autofilter method of Range class failed"

```
Set wkb1 = Workbooks.Open("D:\Meru\Work\Trace Reports\Automation\Macro Codes\" & CFname & "\Daily Pivots -" & CfolderN & ".xls")

With wkb1.Worksheets("winloss")
    LastRow5 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    'MsgBox LastRow
    Set My_Range = .Range("V1:V" & LastRow5)
    'MsgBox My_Range
    My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=22, Criteria1:="Won", Operator:=xlFilterValues
  '   LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row

    .UsedRange.Copy
End With

With wkb1.Worksheets("Trial")
    .Range(.Cells(1, "A"), .Cells(LastRow5, "A")).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End With
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the range to be filtered contains only one column, it should be like this...

```
My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Won", Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Comment: You're welcome Meru! Glad I could help. Please take a moment to accept the answer to mark your question as Solved.